# Reading an Word file using NSTextStorage

Tags: ios, nstextstorage

I thought I read in the documentation that NSTextStorage could read a Word file. I did this:

```
     textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithFileURL:url 
                  options:0 documentAttributes:&attributes error:&error]
```

And I get the following error:

```
2014-04-01 15:08:52.322 Text Display[4665:90b] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" 
UserInfo=0x8b80d40 {NSFilePath=/Users/Ahab/Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator/7.1/Applications/BCFFFD16-41DE-4E09-8E79-0061A0607B91/Text Display.app/sample.docx}
```

Am I wrong here in that Word documents cannot really be read?
Or is something else wrong?

I should have added that reading the same as RTF works. I my through was either DOCX cannot be read or the attributes have to bet set somehow. Unfortunately, the apple omitted that documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOC files can be read in to an NSTextStorage, but DOCX files presently cannot.

Comment: You are correct. Oddly, you cannot read pages files. I do note that when I read a DOC file, I get a lot of garbage at the start (looks like a paragraph's worth of non-printable characters.